# NSOutlineView ReloadItem Does Not Work

Tags: nsoutlineview

When calling reloadItem() on my NSOutlineView items do not seem to be updated. ReloadData() updates them fine. As does rowForItem() followed by reloadDataForRowIndexes().

Through debugging I have discovered viewForTableColumn() is never called after a ReloadItem(). This seems strange as why then does this function exist?

So why don't I just use rowForItem() & reloadDataForRowIndexes() you say. Because if the item has isGroupItem returning true, then reloadDataForRowIndexes does nothing. I think I read somewhere that this is because the groupItems do not have columns or something?

Therefore I cannot update the groupItem rows in my NSOutlineView without calling reloadData(). This prevents me using any insert and delete animations... and I want animations.

Has anyone found a way to update groupItem rows using reloadItem??? or any other way which doesn't need to reload entire outline view?

Best,

Gavin

Comment: Oh I am using swift & cocoa in case that matters. Also the NSOutlineView is View Based

Comment: looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963031/nsoutlineview-reloaditem-has-no-effect?s=1|2.7867

Answer (score 0):

Old question but i still came across this today after hours of having similar problems. Anyhow i eventually found this on the developer forums https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/68477

Essentially an `NSOutlineView` compares via reference with all of its `for item: Any?` functions which means structs will not work.

Change my structs to classes did the trick