# How to make NSOutlineView reload group items?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I can't make "isGroup" items in an NSOutlineView individually reload.

I'm using both the `reloadItem` and `reloadData(forRowIndexes:columnIndexes:)` APIs, but the view doesn't update. This problem is specific to "isGroup" items. I can reload normal items without trouble.

This project demonstrates the problem:

https://github.com/jessegrosjean/NSOutlineViewReloadGroupItemTest

Comment: You didn't mention `reloadItem(_:, reloadChildren:)`.  Have you tried that one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSOutlineView reloadItem: has no effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963031/nsoutlineview-reloaditem-has-no-effect)

Comment: Any success fixing this?