# NSOutlineView: sometimes a row is not editable (just beeps)

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview, first-responder, nstablecellview

I have a view-based `NSOutlineView` configured with a dataSource and delegate. It consists of two columns a custom `NSTableCellView` class.

Entries in the outline view are editable by selecting a row and pressing the `Return` key. Everything is set up according the docs and works fine most of the time.

However, sometimes when I press `Return` while a row is selected, the cell's text field does not enter into edit mode. It just beeps.

I can still enter edit mode by "long clicking" on the text field. For some reason, the `Return` key event is sometimes handled differently by the outline view.

I captured two stacktraces:

**#1 Working as expected:**

[image: working]

You can see that from `keyDown()` the event eventually makes the cell's text field the first responder.

**#2 Beeping**

[image: beep]

I put a breakpoint at `NSBeep` and you can see that the key even takes a different path this time.

I suspect that maybe the internal state of the outline view or underlying `NSTableView` is mixed up...

How can I troubleshoot this from here? Which steps does the outline view take to determine if a row can be edited after the Return key was pressed?

**Update**

I did some more debugging (thanks to @Willeke for the tip about the breakpoint). I managed to tack it down to this:

- Return key is pressed
- `NSOutlineView.keydown`
- ...
- `NSOutlineView.selectedRow`

  - outline view checks which row is selected
- `NSOutlineView.rowView(atRow row: Int, makeIfNecessary: Bool)`

  - outline view retrieves the selected row view
- `NSTableRowView.nextValidKeyView`

  - current row view is asked for the next valid key view
- `NSTableRowView.nextKeyView`

  - Now this returns sometimes `nil` and the app just beeps. Most of the time it returns the `NSTableCellView` for that row containing the `NSTextField` that is then made first responder and hence editable.

Now the question is why is the next key view `nil` sometimes? I click on the outline view's row so it does have the focus/is selected...

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the methods in backtrace #1 to check which one isn't called. Step through the last method that is called (`-[NSTableView _viewBasedAttemptToPerformClickOnViewOfClass:]`?) to find out where it fails. What's special about `FileNameTextField`? Is this question related to [NSOutlineView row not editable by “Return” key anymore after reloading a different table view cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60397648/nsoutlineview-row-not-editable-by-return-key-anymore-after-reloading-a-differe)?

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for your tip. My assembly is a bit rusty but I managed to track it down to `nextKeyVew`. I updated the question. About `FileNameTextField`: nothing too special. It selects the base name of a file name without the extension. The bug occurs even if I comment out all special behavior.

Comment: Is the cell view replaced when `NSTableRowView.nextKeyView` returns `nil`?

Comment: No, not as far as I can tell. The item is a child item of a folder item. I can reproduce the problem like this: 1) programmatically select item, 2) programmatically select another item, 3) programmatically select the first item, 4) click on the first item & press Return key → beeps. If I perform step 4) right after step 1) it works just fine. My selection process does this: calls `NSOutlineView.expandItem()` for all parent items + call `selectRowIndexes(itemRow)` + `scrollRowToVisible(itemRow).

Comment: I noticed thatt the key view loop of the row view isn't always updated when the cell view is replaced by another one (from the reuse queue). Possible fix: subclass `NSTableRowView`, override `nextValidKeyView` and return the first focusable control in the row.

Comment: Great, subclassing `NSTableRowView` did the trick! Thank you very much! Would you like to add your workaround as answer so that I can mark it as accepted (so you get proper credit for it)?